# How to determine switcher and double switcher in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my data

```
user_id channel
1       A
1       A
1       A
2       A
2       B
2       B
2       B
3       A
3       B
3       B
3       A
3       A
4       A
4       B
```

What I need is make function that can filter switcher (user who switch at least once)

```
user_id
    2
    3
    4
```

And filter double switcher (user who switch at least twice)

```
user_id
    3
```

Since real data is quite big, it's better if the answerer can give generalization for next order of switcher, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.groupby('user_id').apply(
    lambda x: np.count_nonzero(x.values[:-1] != x.values[1:])
)

user_id
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    1
dtype: int64
```

---

**filter**

```
df.groupby('user_id').apply(
    lambda x: np.count_nonzero(x.values[:-1] != x.values[1:])
).compress(lambda x: x > 0)

user_id
2    1
3    2
4    1
dtype: int64
```

Or

```
df.groupby('user_id').apply(
    lambda x: np.count_nonzero(x.values[:-1] != x.values[1:])
).compress(lambda x: x > 1)

user_id
3    2
dtype: int64
```